# How to join static table once and use it in building complex queries

Tags: sql, oracle

```
--table 1
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    e_id      NUMBER(10),
    test_col1  NUMBER(10)
);

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(1,62);

--table 2
CREATE TABLE test2 (
    e_id      NUMBER(10),
    test_col2  NUMBER(10)
);

INSERT INTO test2 VALUES(1,63);

--Static table
CREATE TABLE lookup_table (
    l_id     NUMBER(10),
    l_value  VARCHAR2(30)
);

INSERT INTO lookup_table VALUES(62,'value_1');
INSERT INTO lookup_table VALUES(63,'value_2');

DB version: Oracle 18c
```

I want to create a view based on table 1, table 2 and static table (lookup/reference table).
Basically I need to pull all the EUCs which are there in table1 along with the two additional columns which is `lookup_value1` and `lookup_value2`. I tried joining the two tables and then joining static table to fetch the `l_value` from lookup table based on the ids present in table1 and table2.

My attempt:

```
SELECT t1.e_id,
lt.l_value AS lookup_value1,
lt1.l_value AS lookup_value2
FROM test1 t1
LEFT JOIN test2 t2 ON(t1.e_id = t2.e_id)
LEFT JOIN lookup_table lt ON(lt.l_id = t1.test_col1)
LEFT JOIN lookup_table lt1 ON(lt1.l_id = t2.test_col2);
```

This is giving me the expected result but here the problem is I need to join `lookup_table`every time I need to fetch the value from this table. In my case, I have joined `lookup_table` twice. Is there any way to join this table only once and fetch the required value from the lookup table instead of joining it again and again which will lead to a performance degradation issue

Comment: Access to small tables multiple times will reuse cached blocks and you will not multiply IO. In parallel execution they are likely to be broadcasted to each slave and you will not face repartitioning. As an alternative you may build `CASE` expression dynamically (for example, via SQL Macro or PTF), but it adds complexity

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, there were two ways to resolve this problem.

1. Use trigger to add one record into the lookup_table. But need to handle l_value filed's value that need to be provided.
2. Don't use lookup_table, add one column(l_value filed's value) into test1 & test2 table in order to save those static data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to have duplicate `e_id` rows the you could use `UNION ALL` and then join once and `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT e_id, l_value1, l_value2
FROM   (
  SELECT t.e_id, t.type, l.l_value
  FROM   ( SELECT e_id, 1 AS type, test_col1 AS test_col FROM test1
           UNION ALL
           SELECT e_id, 2, test_col2 FROM test2 ) t
         LEFT OUTER JOIN lookup_table l
         ON (t.test_col = l.l_id)
)
PIVOT ( MAX(l_value) FOR type IN (1 AS l_value1, 2 AS l_value2) )
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | E_ID | L_VALUE1 | L_VALUE2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | value_1 | value_2 |

---

Or, the same query using sub-query factoring clauses:

```sql
WITH complex_query1 (e_id, test_col1) AS (
  SELECT * FROM test1
),
complex_query2 (e_id, test_col2) AS (
  SELECT * FROM test2
),
combined_query (e_id, type, test_col) AS (
  SELECT e_id, 1, test_col1 FROM complex_query1
UNION ALL
  SELECT e_id, 2, test_col2 FROM complex_query2
),
lookup_values (e_id, type, l_value) AS (
  SELECT t.e_id, t.type, l.l_value
  FROM   combined_query t
         LEFT OUTER JOIN lookup_table l
         ON (t.test_col = l.l_id)
)
SELECT e_id, l_value1, l_value2
FROM   lookup_values
PIVOT ( MAX(l_value) FOR type IN (1 AS l_value1, 2 AS l_value2) )
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f6b80f08063f55f8f7b9f9a39651ae53)*

Comment: Thanks for this but actually I have a complex query to prepare which will require adding this lookup table to fetch different values multiple times. So, wondering if I join multiple times this table will it hamper performance or is there any alternative to join lookup table once and use it as many times as needed